# What verse in the Bible talks about bad people preaching the gospel being a good thing?

Tags: gospel, preaching, verse-identification

Some time ago I read this verse about greedy people who announce the gospel because of their own greed, which is a bad thing, but it ends up that this is a good thing because more people will hear about Jesus.

I can't tell if the verse says exactly this, but I'm pretty sure that is something very likely. Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  If you haven't don so already, be sure to read up on how this site is [a little different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your question, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Comment: Welcome to the site! [This kind of question is problematic](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/4200/6071) and the community is [only recently considering allowing them](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5775/6071). To ensure that this question is the best that it can be, please [edit] it to [specify the exact words you have tried searching for, and give us a list of verses you have found that are *not* what you are looking for](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/5819/6071).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what you've said, i can almost certainly say this is Philippians 1:18

> But what does it matter? The important thing is that in every way, whether from false motives or true, Christ is preached. And because of this I rejoice. Yes, and I will continue to rejoice ([Philippians 1:18](http://biblehub.com/philippians/1-18.htm) NVI)

This passage's context is pretty much like what you've read: bad people preaching isn't bad *at all*, God can use them to reach a good purpose.

But it is not about **greedy** people, you read in verse 15 that he is talking about people who preach out of "envy and rivalry". But the essence is quite the same.